# Implementing bash operators for shell in c++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, execvp

I'm trying to implement the `||`, `&&`, and `;` operators in a bash shell I am making. What I am trying to do, is use a `int` as a flag that would be set to 1 if it was successful or 0 if it was not. My issue is that even if I enter an invalid operation such as `ls -apples` it sets the flag to 1. I also get the error message

> ls: invalid option -- 'e'
>   Try 'ls --help' for more information

so I think that means it technically is executing? 
How do I keep track of whether `execvp` took a invalid operation?
Here is my code:

```
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t waitId; 
    int status; 
    //forks into two processes 
    pid = fork();
    //There was an error during fork
    if (pid < 0) 
    {
        successFlag = 0; 
        perror("There was an error");
    } 
    else if (pid == 0) 
    {
        //must be cast because our function expects a char *const argv[]
        if (execvp(command[0], (char**)command) < 0) 
        { 
            //error at execvp
            successFlag = 0; 
            perror("There was an error executing the process");
        }
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else 
    {
        do 
        {
          waitId = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
          if(waitId == -1){
              successFlag = 0; 
              perror("Error in parent process");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }

        } 

        while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }
    //use this flag to determine whether the process was a success
    successFlag = 1;
```

Comment: You're right, the ls command ran. If I understand your problem statement correctly, you want to determine if the command sent a failure. In which case you want the "error code" (exit code) returned by the command.

Comment: What I did, was look at the `status` value of of `waitpid`. I found that any value that was not 0 was invalid. I made a boolean flag to handle this. Is this valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to look at the number that `status` returns. The sign would tell you whether it was successful or not.